# Angular and Ionic runs with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

In a discussion about performance, the question arose:

Angular and also Ionic needs the Node.js to be served or the dist folder is just what we need to serve in the client side app?
Node.js is only a tool to develop the solution or is used to serve too?

What i mean is if Angular needs Node.js in runtime production (after development)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a ionic project we need node js. By using node we install ionic angular framework which is available in NPM(Node Package Manager). so when we create a project using CLI, we will get ionic angular package installed in that.

Comment: OK, but after development, when the application is served on internet. Its needs Node.js to be served or Node.js transpiles the ts code into  files (such as html, css an .js) that don't need Node.js in runtime?

Comment: ionic uses node js for development, testing , deployment and for build purpose, if it is a ionic angular project. now we can bundle node js with ionic. For that node js is mandatory in run time as it is getting used as back-end.

Comment: That I understand, I'm only in doubt about an front-end application. My question is, if is the Node.js that makes the animations and other stuff. This because I've tried to run locally my built home page in dist folder and nothing had happened. In heroku that have happened so easy.

Comment: As i have mentioned above node js is used for  development, testing , deployment and for build purpose not for animations. so if node js is not available , your application wont be able to deploy or run. i donot have any idea about heroku.